# How to determine which dynamic button was clicked in android?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a dynamic button in oncreate, i didnt put any button in my XML.

```
LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
Button btnAttendance,btnSched;
btnAttendance = new Button(this);
btnSched = new Button(this);
btnAttendance.setOnClickListener(this);
btnSched.setOnClickListener(this);
table.addView(btnAttendance);
        table.addView(btnSched);
```

// This is my OnClick method that i createed in implementing  my listener:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BackgroundWorker fetchRiddles = new BackgroundWorker(DashActivity.this,"retrieveRiddles");
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case 1:  // in this case i usually put "R.id.Button1:" but my problem is that my buttons are dynamic
            fetchRiddles.execute("0,"+username);
            break;
        case 2:
            fetchRiddles.execute("1,"+username);
            break;
    }
```

How to determine which button was clicked using switch? My buttons are created dynamically without putting any buttons inside my xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the ID programmatically :

```
btnAttendance = new Button(this);
btnAttendance.setId(100);
btnSched = new Button(this);
btnSched.setId(200);
```

then compare:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BackgroundWorker fetchRiddles = new BackgroundWorker(DashActivity.this,"retrieveRiddles");
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case 100:  // in this case i usually put "R.id.Button1:" but my problem is that my buttons are dynamic
            fetchRiddles.execute("0,"+username);
            break;
        case 200:
            fetchRiddles.execute("1,"+username);
            break;
    }
```